# innerHTML works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

If we execute below code in Firefox 23, both alert boxes show correct value. When I execute the same in Chrome 28, second alert shows blank window.

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="mappingIDinput"/>
```

**JS**

```
alert(mappingId);
document.getElementById("mappingIDinput").innerHTML=mappingId;  
alert(document.getElementById("mappingIDinput").innerHTML);
```

How can I save & retrieve value in hidden input field which works across browsers(ignore IE if required).

Comment: An `<input>` tag cannot have other tags inside. I can't understand how `.innerHTML` works in Firefox. (Is the jQuery tag relevant? Your code doesn't use any jQuery feature.)

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario, jQuery is being used on the page though not here.

Comment: `.innerHTML` is used to get/set the contents that is present within the tag element. Example, if you have a div like `<div id='test'>Some Content</div>`, using `.innerHTML` you can get the `Some Content` that is present within the `div` and `</div>`. This should not (and cannot?) be used to get/set values of input fields. `.value` should be used for getting/setting the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for input field use  value not html to get their value

**IN JAVASCRIPT**

**SET**

```
document.getElementById("mappingIDinput").value="abc";
```

**GET**

```
alert(document.getElementById("mappingIDinput").value);
```

**in jQuery**

**SET**

```
$("#mappingIDinput").val("abc");
```

**GET**

```
 alert($("#mappingIDinput").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use innerHTML to set value for an input tag but use value or val() in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use .val() for all inputs. Inner html is for   etc.

```
$("#mappingIDinput").val(mappingId);
```

Cheers